# mapView didTapInfoWindowOfMarker method does not work? Google Maps iOS SDK

Tags: google-maps-sdk-ios

Anyone else experiencing this? I'm using the latest Google Maps SDK for iOS. This is what I have in the didTapInfoWindowOfMarker method :

```
- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapInfoWindowOfMarker:(id<GMSMarker>)marker {
  NSLog(@"yes");
}
```

Not getting any response in my output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you didn't add delegate and protocol for your GMSMapView object, something like:

```
mapView_.delegate = self;
```

in loadView method.

So, the full  `- (void)loadView`and delegate method should be:

```
@interface ViewController () <GMSMapViewDelegate> // Add this if you haven't
{
    id<GMSMarker> myMarker;
}


- (void)loadView {
  GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:-33.8683
                                                          longitude:151.2086
                                                               zoom:6];
  mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
  mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;
  mapView_.delegate = self; // This sets the delegate for map view
  self.view = mapView_;
}

- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapInfoWindowOfMarker:(id<GMSMarker>)marker {
  NSLog(@"yes"); // And now this should work.
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Feeling like an idiot for forgetting to set its delegate :(